# What are these unusual characters alone in seals?

Tags: character-identification, seal

What are these unusual characters ?
They are alone on each seal.

[image]

Comment: Please always put a new line between the picture and a text, otherwise the question looks very badly formatted on screens with wide displays. Also, please ask one question at a time, to keep the questions and answers useful for other users of this site; there are six seals here (and thus six questions). Also, show your attempt in each one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first one might be 杏 and the second one is 帝.I think these are ancient Chinese Characters.The third character looks like Small Seal Script.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first one is 夻 and the 3rd one is 䨜
I don't think those are so much unusual characters as an atypical font face.  Characters drawn for a seal tend to be drawn idiosyncratically like that.